# SQL freetext() not working on some columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-indexing

I have a table which contains 7 columns and I have created a full text index on the table. However I noticed that a search using freetext() does not return any rows on 2 of the columns
Its returns rows on other columns.

**Here is my query**

```
select * from dbo.ModelCategoryValues
where freetext(economyvalues,'24,29')
and freetext(featurevalues,'10')
and freetext(pricerangevalues,'15')
and freetext(performancevalues,'18,20')
and freetext(economyvalues,'22,24')
and freetext(usevalues,'28')
```

This returns expected results

However when I run the below no rows are returned

```
select * from dbo.ModelCategoryValues
where freetext(cartypevalues,'1')
```

I can see rows corresponding to the above data. I have tried everything from re-populating index to re-creating it but no success.

Comment: Please share schema of this table.

Comment: Here is the db diagram
https://www.dropbox.com/s/hbjhucghck8sfpz/Capture.PNG?dl=0

Comment: Data Types of columns?

Comment: Obvious question - but is cartypevalues actually in the index?

Comment: Here is the entire db schema 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/hbjhucghck8sfpz/Capture.PNG?dl=0

Comment: yes, all the columns except for the variantid and categoryid are in the index.The index is working well on all other columsn except for carseatvalues and cartypevalues columns. Using contains() does not work either

Comment: here is the data in the table. I want to be able to pass one or many of atleast one column and do the search https://www.dropbox.com/s/uqoezvnrvp4u6pi/Capture1.PNG?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

**FREETEXT** by default excludes the records having "**STOPLIST**" Values.
To resolve the problem, set the StopList to 'OFF' using following query :-

```
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON DealerSearch SET STOPLIST = OFF
```